# Can I track on point the surface of Mars, for instance, a rovers's landing site, using PyEphem

Tags: pyephem

Can I track on point the surface of Mars, for instance, a rovers's landing site, using PyEphem  and if the particular point would be visible from a certain point on Earth or the period as well, of visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think that the answer is no: PyEphem offers support from the underlying libastro library for the longitude of our of own Moon that is facing us, and for the longitude of Jupiter that is facing us; but not, it appears, for Mars.

**Response to comment:**

Since the Moon always points the same face at us, the approximate answer to your comment about the Moon is that “0° longitude is always pointing toward us, so that the Moon's face visible to us is the longitudes 0–90° and 270-360°.”

There is, however, a slight wobble in the exact lunar longitude that is facing Earth's center at any given moment. You can look at the property `moon.libration_long` to find out, for a given moment, how far east or west of “perfectly facing us” the Moon currently is.

**Further response:**

You can ask for how Jupiter is facing us by asking for its Central Meridian Longitude, either using System I or System II, like this:

```
import ephem
j = ephem.Jupiter()
j.compute('2013/1/1')
print j.cmlI
print j.cmlII
```

The results are longitudes measured as radians that print out as degrees:

```
64:29:25.5
169:52:16.2
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thankyou Sir. Can you help me out with Jupiter?